# Are there any downsides to creating a stub by subclassing in Swift?

Tags: unit-testing, swift-language

I'm mainly interested in answers in regards to a Swift language, but more general answers are always welcome.

I want to test a class (CUT), and for that I will use dependency injection. Now, I can:

1. Create some protocol that my CUT will use, which some concrete class and some stub class will conform to.
2. Just use concrete class in my CUT, and have a stub class as a subclass of concrete class. Stub class will override **just** those methods that CUT is using from concrete class.

Example for option 1:

```
// PRODUCTION CODE

class A {
   func incrementedValueOf(_ b: BProtocol) -> Int {
       return b.value + 1
   }
}

protocol BProtocol {
    func value() -> Int
}

class B: BProtocol {
    func value() -> Int { return calculateValueSomehow() }
    func calculateValueSomehow() -> Int { return ... }
}

// TEST CODE

class BStub: BProtocol {
    var valueToProvide: Int = 0
    func value() -> Int { return valueToProvide }
}

class ATests: XCTestCase {

    func testIncrementedValueOf() {
        let bStub = BStub()
        bStub.valueToProvide = 11
        let a = A()
        XCTAssertEqual(a.incrementedValueOf(bStub), bStub.valueToProvide + 1)
    }
}
```

Example for option 2:

```
// PRODUCTION CODE

class A {
   func incrementedValueOf(_ b: B) -> Int {
       return b.value + 1
   }
}

// Note: BProtocol is removed

class B {
    func value() -> Int { return calculateValueSomehow() }
    func calculateValueSomehow() -> Int { return ... }
}

// TEST CODE

class BStub: B {
    var valueToProvide: Int = 0
    override func value() -> Int { return valueToProvide }

    // Note: calculateValueSomehow is not overridden
}

class ATests: XCTestCase {

    func testIncrementedValueOf() {
        let bStub = BStub()
        bStub.valueToProvide = 11
        let a = A()
        XCTAssertEqual(a.incrementedValueOf(bStub), bStub.valueToProvide + 1)
    }
}
```

Is there a downside in using option 2?

- `A` and `B` are more tightly coupled?
- Is there some problem if class `B` is a part of a different framework? Maybe it will be a problem in future Swift if `A` uses some method from `B` which is `public` but not `open`, so it will not be overridable (for example `value()`)?

Comment: `A and B are more tightly coupled?` -- How?  Their code is exactly the same in both examples.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought they are because in example 2 `A` uses type `B` where in example 1 `A` doesn't know about `B`, just about `BProtocol`. But I'm not sure. So they are not?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, that doesn't have anything to do with your testing, does it?  That's just normal software design.  While testing should inform your design decisions (i.e. your code should be easily testable), I don't think it should drive them, necessarily.

Comment: Which approach do you believe is easier to use (i.e. will make development proceed faster), and will be more readily adopted by you and others working on the code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, that is a good question. :) I believe that option 2 is easier and nicer, so that is why I want to check if there are some downsides, and Google wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

swift goes into more protocol orientated design

i would go for `Option 1`

when you conform a protocol instead of a special class you can exchange the stub in any kind of type (class, struct, enum). and the code is not coupled to this specific class.

so you can mock a complicated class with a simple struct.

Answer (score 0):

One potential downside is that your stub isn't starting from clean. Unless you purposely override all methods, which is error prone, your subclassed stub will inherit behaviour from the base class, which may be unexpected.

For example, if A is implemented like this:

```
class A {
    func incrementedValueOf(b : B) -> Int {
        b.doSomethingUnexpected();
        return b.value() + 1;
    }

    func doSomethingUnexpected() {
        //melt things
    }
}
```

Then because the stubbed B subclasses from B, your stub by default has inherited the implementation of DoSomethingUnexpected() and this will be called by the test. Maybe that's a useful ability though, or maybe it makes it a bit hazy what tests are doing, as the stub may not really be a stub anymore.